# Multiple if statements in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, gis, dos

I have to prompt the user for a file name, then check if there are three necessary filetypes (.shp, .shx, .dbf) of that name and also check for an optional fourth (.prj)

```batch
 @echo off


set /p basename = Enter a file name: 

if exist %basename%.shp (
    if exist %basename%.shx (
        if exist %basename%.dbf (
            if exist %basename%.prj (
            echo %basename% is a complete shapefile.
            ) else ( echo %basname% is an acceptable shapefile.)
            )
            )
            ) else ( echo shapefile is incomplete)
```

Forgive my garbage syntax/formatting, but everything I pass in returns "shapefile is incomplete".

Comment: Have you tried separating each of those `IF`'s out into a command prompt session and trying them individually to see what your results are? What about adding some `echo` statements to see how far you are getting? Is the basename that you are entering an absolute or relative path?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems.

1) Spaces are significant when defining variables. Your SET /P statement created a variable named "basename ", with a trailing space at the end. But your IF statements are using a variable without the space in the name.

2) Your ELSE clause only fires if the outer IF is FALSE. If the .shp file exists, but one of the other required files is missing, then there should be no output.

3) You should put quotes around the full name in the IF statement, just in case there are spaces or poison characters in the name.

The easiest way to get the correct logic is to use a temporary variable to record if one of the files is missing.

I would not use a bunch of individual IF statements. Instead I would use a FOR loop to shorten and simplify the code.

```
@echo of
setlocal
set /p "basename=Enter a file name: "
set "missing="
for %%X in (shp shx dbf) if not exist "%basename%.%%X" set missing=1
if defined missing (
  echo shapefile is incomplete
) else if exist "%basename%.prj" (
  echo "%basename%" is a complete shapefile
) else echo "%basename%" is an acceptable shapefile
```